# Unable to install kodi 17 Krypton on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: kodi

I've followed the official guide here

http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Install_Kodi_for_Linux

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

Nothing to do. No upgrade from 16 (Jarvis) to 17. I always get the "Kodi from debian" (top left in Kodi home screen): it's always Jarvis 16.1

I've also tried to purge old Kodi, removed `~/.kodi/` directory, and tried a fresh install. Nothing, no way to get version 17.3.
I've tried the nightly ppa too: needless to say, nothing!

---

As requested:

**`lsb_release -a`**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety
```

**`apt-cache policy kodi`**

```
kodi:
  Installed: 16.1+dfsg1-2
  Candidate: 2:17.3+git20170525.0741-final-0yakkety
  Version table:
     2:17.3+git20170525.0741-final-0yakkety 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
 *** 16.1+dfsg1-2 500
        500 http://ba.mirror.garr.it/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I had to put spaces in links because I do not have enough reputation.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to post more info, for example, `apt-cache policy kodi` and `lsb_release -a` .

Comment: Run `sudo apt purge kodi kodi-bin kodi-data` then `sudo apt install kodi kodi-bin` mighy work not sure, kodi is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem.
I think it was a package problem.
The following procedure worked great, hope this can helpful:

1. removed all related kodi repository:

   ```
   sudo ppa-purge team-xmbc/ppa
   sudo ppa-purge team-xbmc/xbmc-nightly
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. purged all kodi related packages:

   ```
   sudo apt purge kodi-data kodi kodi-bin
   ```
3. cleaned apt cache and checked everything was ok

   ```
   sudo apt-cache policy kodi
   ```
4. Added kodi repository once again

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
   ```
5. performed a clean install

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install kodi kodi-bin
   ```

Now version 17.3 Krypton is installed.
Thanks for all your contributions.